# Enforce Athena column number matching

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Whenever I create tables in AWS Athena, Athena will create the table even if the number of columns I'm requesting is smaller or larger than the number of columns in the dataset (regardless on if I'm using CSV files or something like Parquet).

Is there anyway to enforce this matching? The situation that I'm having is that we have datasets placed into a central location. Then, we run an automated process which needs the exact column names in order to dispatch the correct queries. The issue is that if a user was to start this automated process and uses one less column or one more column than the true dataset, we basically can botch the entire job (possibly running queries that can be much more expensive depending on the column). My goal is that this will help alleviate some potential human error.

The code that I'm writing is in Python. I am worried about trying to check this beforehand by pulling in the S3 file because these files that we are running the queries on are quite large (between 500MB and 2GB).

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I normally use an AWS Glue **crawler** to create the table definitions in Athena, based on the contents of the data files. This way, the table matches the actual contents of the files.

Answer (score 0):

The "creation" of a table in Athena is a logical mapping (Schema) that doesn't care anything about your data. You can even create a table on an "empty" folder in S3.

You have a few options to create a matching validation:

- Try a query to the table after it was created. You can `SELECT count(*) FROM <TABLE_NAME>` and check that the query doesn't fail.
- Use [Glue Crawler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html), instead of creating manually. If the data structure is simple enough or you can create the needed classifiers for complex data, it will be able to create the correct schema for your data.